# Get the length of the values in object

Tags: javascript

I want to get the length of values from an object. If the value has no length i should get `0 length`, if value exists i should get value.

```js
const object1 = {
  a: '',
  b: '5'
};

function app() {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
    console.log(key, value)
    return {
      [key]: !object1[key].length ? '0 length' : value
    }
  }
}

console.log(app())
```

**Question**:

1. Why i get just first value from object?

```css
{
  "a": "0 length"
}
```

expect:

```js
{
  "a": "0 length",
  "b": 1
}
```

2. Why now i get in `console.log(key, value)` just the first value-key, but if i delete the return statement i get both value-key?

```js
const object1 = {
  a: '',
  b: '5'
};

function app() {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
    console.log(key, value)
    // return {
    //     [key] : !object1[key].length ? '0 length' : value
    //  }
  }
}

console.log(app())
```

Comment: Having the `return` in your `for` loop exits the `app` function on the first iteration. What exactly do you want the return value to be because your _expected_ example does not represent a valid JS data structure

Comment: Also, how does the `"5"` become `5`?  Are there any other sorts of transformations that should occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are returning from very first value inside `for` you are getting only one value in result.

Instead of that take one variable for ex `let result = {}`; Assign length values to it inside `for` as `result[key] = value.toString().length || '0 length';` and then `return result;`.

Try it below.

```js
const object1 = {
  a: '',
  b: '5'
};

function app() {
  let result = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
    // console.log(key, value)
    result[key] = value.toString().length || '0 length';
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(app());
```

---

If your expected output is `array` then use like below. For array result you can also use `map` with like shown in `app2`.

```js
const object1 = {
  a: '',
  b: '5'
};

function app() {
  let result = [];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
    result.push({[key]: value.toString().length || '0 length'});
  }
  return result;
}

function app2() {
  return Object.entries(object1).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value.toString().length || '0 length'}));
}

console.log(app());
console.log(app2());
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` exits the loop after first iteration

Perhaps you should do something like this

```js
const object1 = {
  a: '',
  b: '5'
};
const newObj = {};

function app() {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
    console.log(key, value)
    newObj[key] = !object1[key].length ? '0 length' : value

  }
  return newObj;
}

console.log(app())
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const object1 = {
  a: '',
  b: '5'
};
 
function app() {
  const result = [];
  for(let key in object1) {
    if(object1[key] && object1[key].length) {
      result.push({[key] :`${object1[key].length} length`});
    } else {
      result.push({[key] :`0 length`});
    }
  }
  return result;
}
  console.log(app())
```